# The best MDX references on the net

Tags: mdx, business-intelligence

What is the best references/links,cheatsheets for the MDX language? Here are a few starters that I have collected. Please share yours :)

- http://www.gumper.com/mdx.html
- http://www.sqlserveranalysisservices.com/OLAPPapers/InventoryManagement%20in%20AS2005v2.htm
- http://www.ssas-info.com/ssas-cheat-sheets/72-cheat-sheets/880-time-mdx-cheat-sheets

Answer (score 2):

It's perhaps hard to look through if you don't know what you're looking for, but the  [Microsoft MDX Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145506.aspx) is actually very good if you know the name of the functions.

Obviously (or perhaps not *that obviously*) the MDX implementation differs between OLAP sources, and the Microsoft reference is tailored towards Analysis Services.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find some MDX documentation (introduction and reference) at : http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/index.html