# Implementing data cube in c#

Tags: data-warehouse, olap, olap-cube

I am trying to implement a multi dimensional data cube in c#. Could somebody point in the direction of resources that would serve as a starting point. I am primarily interested in data structures needed to implement the cube.

Comment: Using Analysis Services?

Comment: I am trying to create a custom analytics engine, analysis services wouldn't suit my needs.

Comment: What kind of query language do you want to use once you've built your multi-dimensional engine ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is helpful, but there is a sourceforge project http://mondrian.pentaho.com/. There is a community edition which is open source, so you may be able to get some ideas on the underlying data structures even though it is not a c# implementation.

There is also a few useful references for MDX at this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515114/the-best-mdx-references-on-the-net)

Comment: Thanks for the MDX links. They are useful.